# how to generate a random sequence

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

````
def random_bitstring_generator(bit_number, backend):
    

    bitstring = ""

    one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit = QuantumCircuit(4,4)
    one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit.h(3)
    one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit.measure(3,3)

    for _ in range(bit_number):
        counts = execute(one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit, backend, shots=8000).result().get_counts()
        bit = list(counts.keys())[0]  
        bitstring += bit

    return bitstring

from qiskit.providers.aer import QasmSimulator

provider = IBMQ.load_account()
ibmq_melbourne = provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
backend = QasmSimulator.from_backend(ibmq_melbourne)

print(random_bitstring_generator(512, backend))```

Using the above  code,
I am only getting an output bit string with all 0's even with changing number of shots.
what is the error leading to incorrect output.
I am trying to generate a long random sequence
````

Comment: I am not able to achieve the results with the implementation given here. As also It gives errors which i am unable to rectify. like ERROR code 3444:login failed though i am logged in with gmail account in Q experience.I mistakenly regenerated the API token, should it have any effect on the error above as i logged out and logged in again too but the error still was the same.I am an open provider user in IBM Q experience

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def random_bitstring_generator(bit_number, backend):
    bitstring = ""

    one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit = QuantumCircuit(1, 1)
    one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit.h(0)
    one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit.measure(0, 0)

    for _ in range(bit_number):
        counts = execute(one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit, backend, shots=1).result().get_counts()
        bit = list(counts.keys())[0]  
        bitstring += bit

    return bitstring

backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
random_bitstring_length = 100
print(random_bitstring_generator(random_bitstring_length, backend) )
```

This would output something like:

```
0000010000010010001000111010001110001000000100110011110110101010111011001100100001100100001101100000
```

Note that the number of **shot is 1** since we just creating some random number and not finding the probability of seeing $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$.

Comment: does this mean that i should be trying to execute with minimum number of qubits because when i am executing the above code  for 3,4 or more qubits the sequence doesn't appear to be random as large number of continuous 0s and 1s appear inside the sequence.Also when i am trying to execute over any prototype like vigo,santiago or ourense it outputs error code 3446:login failed though i am logged in IBM Q Experience with gmail account. I am only using quantum lab /Q Experience GUI and do not know much of python for Qiskit.